# Image(s) not showing when using nodejs with handlebars (.hbs)

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I have tried to search for an answer here but nothing so far worked, not many threads about handlebars. Im at my 2nd year of coding and struggling to get images to show up on my node app.

I have this on app.js and below that the code im trying to get image to show up on the .hbs file:

```
app.use(express.static('img/'));

 <img src="bckground.jpg" alt="teeest" />
```

Thank you in advance if someone knows what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you are serving your application at "http://localhost:3000", and your web page is "http://localhost:3000/index.html", you are requesting the image "bckground.jpg", so the browser will try to load "http://localhost:3000/bckground.jpg". This is wrong, because you are serving the static images folder under the "img" path, so the image is available at "http://localhost:3000/img/bckground.jpg".

If your application is being served at the "root" path of the domain, then this should work for you:

```html
<img src="/img/bckground.jpg" />
```

Note the initial "/" at the image path. This means that the path will be calculated from the root folder of the domain. You should take this into account if you are serving your application in a subfolder.